# what does for="power" do in this situation?

Tags: angular

Why does this label have for="power" declared?  What does it do?

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="power">Hero Power</label>
<select class="form-control" id="power" required>
<option *ngFor="let p of powers" [value]="p">{{p}}</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats pure HTML and not related to Angular

Answer (score 1):

It designates which input the label corresponds to and is therefore bound to (which is significant for styling and semantic-ness). The select element has an id of "power" so when displaying this form the browser knows that "Hero Power" is a label for it.

Comment: Thanks, when is this useful specifically?

Comment: If a user clicks on the label, the cursor will jump to the corresponding input field. It's also useful for helping screen readers / accessibility options do their jobs correctly

Answer (score 0):

Its just a declaration syntax for HTML.

Basically by doing this you are specifying that label is mapped with the form control having Id='power'.

So at the time of creation of DOM the label is mapped to HTML element having id='power'.

Hope this helps.